# Mudar cor fundo célula tabela

Tags: javascript

Estou a tentar mudar a coloração do fundo de células cujos valores são iguais ao dia que o usuário acessa o site.
A variável `$dataa` guarda as datas de cada nome...

Formatação tabela (tá dentro dum loop php):

```
echo "
<tr>
  <td id=\"linha".$l."\">".$nomes[$l]."</td>
  <td class=\"dataa\">".$dataa[$l]."</td>
</tr>
";
```

Tentativa de coloração:

```
<SCRIPT>

<?php

echo "var obj = new Array();";

for ($k=0; $k<16; $k++){

 if ( $data_pro_php[$k] == '23' ) {

    echo " 
    obj[$k] = getElementById(\"linha$k\");
    obj[$k].style.backgroundColor='#FF0000'; 
    ";

 }

}

?>

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Acho que está a fazer da maneira mais dificil. Podia fazer isto no PHP quando gera o HTML, ou no JavaScript. Assim é um meio termo que fica confuso. Pode colocar mais código desse PHP? Entretanto tem um erro no JS: `obj[$k] = getElementById(\"linha$k\");` falta "document" deve ser `obj[$k] = document.getElementById(\"linha$k\");`

Comment: Funcionou? Posso colocar resposta, pode ser que outros tenham o mesmo problema...

Comment: sim. Era a falta do document.

Comment: Se achar que vale a pena, põe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um erro no seu JavaScript, falta `document` no código.

Teste assim:

```
echo " 
    obj[$k] = document.getElementById(\"linha$k\");
    obj[$k].style.backgroundColor='#FF0000'; 
";
```

Poderia no entanto fazer isso no PHP quando gera o HTML, ou passar uma array para o Javascript e iterar lá.

Mas corrigindo essa falta deve funcionar.

Se fizer isso em PHP poderia dar uma classe especial a essas `td`. Algo como:

```
$classe = $dataa[$l] == 23 ? 'dataa diaCerto' : 'dataa';
echo "
    <tr>
      <td id=\"linha".$l."\">".$nomes[$l]."</td>
      <td class=\"".$classe."\">".$dataa[$l]."</td>
    </tr>
";
```

e no CSS:

```
.diaCerto{ background-color: #FF0000';}
```

Comment: A razão pra isso é que o objetivo real não é esse. Tentei fazer um código em javascript simples para ver se eu tava fazendo certo. Agora adaptei pro meu uso.